# Phpass login not working

Tags: php, authentication, phpass

I´m changing my register and login to a different encryption (Phpass) because everybody is saying that md5 is not safe anymore. I managed myself to put the register function working but cant figure out why login aint working. This code is running with no errors but its not passing from this line `if($stm->rowCount()>0){}`

Please ignore the commented code, its my old login version. Anyother suggestions are welcome!

```
  include("include/connection.php");
        require_once('include/PasswordHash.php');

        function login($db){
            if (isset($_GET["type"])){  
                if($_GET["type"]=="log" && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])){

                    session_start();

                    $email = $_POST['email'];
                    $password = $_POST['password'];
                    $hasher = new PasswordHash(8, false);

                    if($email=='' || $password==''){
                        echo "<font style='background-color: #F9C5CA'>Error: Please fill the required fields.</font>";
                    }else{

                        //$password = md5($password);
                        $pass = $hasher->HashPassword($_POST['password']);

                        $sql = "SELECT email,password,id FROM user WHERE email=? AND password=?";
                        $stm = $db->prepare($sql);
                        $stm->execute(array($email,$pass));
                        $row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                        /*if($stm->rowCount()>0){

                            $_SESSION['id']=$row['id'];
                            header('Location: cpanel/#welcome');
                        }else{
                            echo "<font style='background-color: #F9C5CA'>Error: Your email and/or password are incorrect. Please try again.</font>";
                        }*/

                        if($stm->rowCount()>0){
                            if ($hasher->CheckPassword($pass,$row['password'])) {
                                $_SESSION['id']=$row['id'];
                                header('Location: cpanel/#welcome');
                                exit();

                            }else{
                                echo "<font style='background-color: #F9C5CA'>Error: Your email and/or password are incorrect. Please try again.</font>";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You need to grab the stored password from the database to be able to verify it with the supplied one.

Comment: Your problem may be the rowCount() function. If you read the [PDO document on rowCount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) it says that you may not get the desired results when using a SELECT statement.

Comment: @Gumbo The stored hashed password on db comes from the Select so i dont think that the problem is there..

Comment: @Kacey So what other method can I use to count rows? This was working before >.<

Comment: No, `PasswordHash` generates a new hash using a new salt; you probably won’t find a record with that hash. Select the hash only by the user name and check the selected password with `CheckPassword`.

Comment: @miguelfsf try replacing your `if($stm->rowCount()>0)` with `if(count($row) != 0)` and see if that works?

Comment: @Gumbo Progressed a little with your tip. But now its jumping to else and getting error message. So the problem its not on the rowCount

Answer (score 0):

You could change the conditional, because there is several ways to replace the `rowCount()`:

If the user exists then `$row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` return an array with the data, if there is no user then will return an empty array:

```
// Count array and check if is greater than 0
if ( count($row) > 0 )
// Check if array is not empty
if ( !empty($row) )
// Simple check. An empty array would return false
if ( $row )
```

Comment: The problem its not there now. Now it gets inside the first if but does not run the second if and jumps to the else. Any tip?

Comment: After this line: `$row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` run this: `die( print_r( $row ) );` That would print the content of the array, so you can check that the function `$hasher->CheckPassword()` get the correct parameters.

Comment: Sorry for the the wait, i had to go dinner. So i tryed die() as you said and its getting the correct parameters. The problem must be on this line `if ($hasher->CheckPassword($pass,$row['password'])) { }` and i cant figure out why >.<

Comment: Forget it, just found the error! I was sending the wrong variables to the checkpassword function. The correct way CheckPassword($password,row['password'])`. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

make sure the hashed password is 60 character, anything more will return false.
I have the same issue and notice my first hashed password was 61 characters.